# Error in CMake path

Tags: cmake

I'm trying to build the Visual Studio project for a kinect demo thing, [rgbddemo](http://nicolas.burrus.name/index.php/Research/KinectRgbDemoV5). According to the instructions on the page, I need to set the PATH variable to include QMAKE from QT. I did that, but I keep getting this error:

CMake Error at CMakeLists.txt:1 (QT4_WRAP_CPP):
  Unknown CMake command "QT4_WRAP_CPP".

From what I could gather from google, it's a problem with CMake knowing where something from QT is. The page I linked above also mentions that you can set the path for QMAKE within CMake, but I don't know how to do that. Does anyone have any suggestions? Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could try inserting the line

```
FIND_PACKAGE(Qt4)
```

into the top-level CMakeLists.txt file after the line

```
INCLUDE("${nestk_BINARY_DIR}/UseNestk.cmake")
```

That should cause it to try to find `qmake` for you. I'm not sure why they don't have that though, but then I'm not that familiar with cmake.

Comment: Ok, adding the FIND_PACKAGE line worked, and it was able to find the QMAKE path, however it's now giving a new error: Unknown CMake command "INSTALL_STANDALONE_BUNDLE". I don't know if CMake is supposed to already know what that is, or if it is supposed to be defined in another file, but I can't find any other reference to it.

Here's the top level CMakeLists.txt: http://pastebin.com/iQiWXqfa
Here's the CMakeLists.txt for the part I'm trying to build: http://pastebin.com/9UrMZJM0

Answer (score 0):

I think this lines in your `CMakeLists.txt` file can help you.

```
find_package(Qt4 Required)
include(${QT_USE_FILE}) #contains path to Qt header

#...

qt4_wrap_cpp(MOC_SOURCES ${MY_HEADERS}) #invoking moc 
add_library(MY_LIB ${SOURCES} ${MOC_SOURCES}) #building lib
target_link_libraries(MY_LIB ${QT_LIBRARIES})

qt4_add_resources(MY_QT_RSC ${RESOURCES}) #if you want to compile from resource files
add_library(MY_LIB_2 ${MY_QT_RSC} {SOURCES})
```