# Building Luminance HDR on Ubuntu

Tags: compilation, cmake, ubuntu-12.04, luminance

I'm following the INSTALL for luminance-hdr-2.3.0, building on Ubuntu 12.04, but I'm getting the following error:

```
root@ben-laptop:/usr/src/luminance# cmake /usr/src/luminance-hdr-2.3.0/src
-- The C compiler identification is GNU
-- The CXX compiler identification is GNU
-- Check for working C compiler: /usr/bin/gcc
-- Check for working C compiler: /usr/bin/gcc -- works
-- Detecting C compiler ABI info
-- Detecting C compiler ABI info - done
-- Check for working CXX compiler: /usr/bin/c++
-- Check for working CXX compiler: /usr/bin/c++ -- works
-- Detecting CXX compiler ABI info
-- Detecting CXX compiler ABI info - done
CMake Error at MainWindow/CMakeLists.txt:14 (QT4_WRAP_CPP):
Unnown CMake command "QT4_WRAP_CPP".
```

Any ideas?

Comment: This is something related with your Qt installation. Try to install qt dev packages.

sudo apt-get install qt4-dev-tools

Comment: otherwise update your CMake, which version are you using? The latest is CMake 2.8.9

Comment: I have already installed qt4-dev-tools, the version of cmake I'm using is 2.8.7 (which is the latest on Ubuntu 12.04)

Comment: have you checked this answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5998100/error-in-cmake-path ?

Comment: Thanks, I had looked at that page already, but not tried the 2nd answer! I had to do a tweak on the second answer and added this to the MainWindow/CMakeLists.txt file: `find_package(Qt4)
include(${QT_USE_FILE})`